# Can't change Runtime-stack version in Distribution center

Tags: azure, deployment

I can't choose runtime-stack version when I try to set up GitHub as source in Azure Distribution center:

[image]

Version 3.1 is the only available option. My app references ASP.NET Core 6 and targets .NET 6 so when I run the Workflow in GitHub to test the build fails. I can easily change from

```
dotnet-version: '3.1.301'
```

to

```
dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
```

in the created workflow file created by Azure.

My question is why can't I choose version in Azure portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot change Version over there. Alternatively, If you want to change the Runtime Stack version, you can change by following below workaround:

Firstly open your app
Then click on Configuration in Settings
Then on General Setting
Then on .Net Version to change to required version

[image]

Comment: This may help some but doesn't really solve the issue. When you try to set up distribution center for a correctly configured Web App, it still only offers .NET 3.1. Then upon execution, visible only on github it seems, we get ".NET Core 3.1 is no longer supported and will not receive security updates in the future."

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and deployment was failing due to the version mismatch.
Solution: Update the .Net Core version master_<>.yml which is generated in Github.
I changed dotnet-version: '3.1' to dotnet-version: '6.0'
Build passed after this change.
[version change code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NceGJ.png)

yml file location: [yml file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCUBD.png)